# PostgreSQL UDF in C using hstore

Tags: c, postgresql, hstore

I'm writing an extension for PostgreSQL in C and I need to use [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html%20hstore) in my UDFs. I can build without errors (using pgxc) but can't use any function in SQL queries.

I've tried `PG_LIBS=hstore` but got undefined reference errors while loading the library.

Next try was `SHLIB_LINK=-L/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib -lhstore` (libhstore.so is not present in the system, only hstore.so, so i've tried with sym and hard links) and got

```
psql:libname.sql:69: ERROR:  could not load library
"/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/libname.so": libhstore.so: cannot open shared 
object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: There really isn't enough information here. I'm guessing based on your shared object names that you're on Linux or BSD, and you seem to be using PostgreSQL 9.1. What are the undefined reference errors you got the first time?

Comment: Yes, it's Linux and it's PostgreSQL 9.1. Undefined references were to Pairs, HStore, and some functions exposed in hstore.h.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From memory, `hstore` doesn't expose much of a C API. You have to use it via the [server programming interface (SPI)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html), using its SQL-level interfaces via your C extension. **UPDATE**: Or, [as Tom Lane points out on the mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/1189.1352441539@sss.pgh.pa.us), use the `fmgr` to invoke the SQL functions it exposes, rather than using the SPI to run full SQL statements. **UPDATE2**: Another option is to `load_external_function("extension", "symbol")` the C functions directly; see `fmgr.h`.

Most of the functions you're trying to use in `hstore` will be declared `static` (so they're local to the hstore module) which is probably why you're getting undefined references. You can only use what's declared in `hstore.h` as a macro or `extern` function. You can't just call any function you find in (say) `hstore_io.c` via direct C linkage.

`PG_LIBS` allows you to specify shared libraries to link to, but `hstore.so` isn't a typical shared library that's intended for linking to during compilation. It's a PostgreSQL extension module that's intended to be `dlopen()`ed by the server. I don't think one extension module linking to another is really supported. That means you probably can't even use the `extern` functions without quite a bit of hacking around.

Use the SPI, the `fmgr`, or `load_external_function`.

If using `load_external_function` you're likely to need to manage memory contexts and other call context. Try to find examples of its use.

See:

- [PGXS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html)
- [Server programming interface (SPI)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html)
- [fmgr](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/fmgr_8h.html)
- [My question about this on pgsql-general](http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/509C9D42.8090003@2ndQuadrant.com)

Comment: Thank you, i'll try both variants as soon as i can get to my computer. ( I also answered to you comment on the question itself just for other people could see, thought i don't think os end even pg version really matter in this case)

Comment: @user1811265 Probably not, as it turns out, but it saves time and it's best to include even if you're not sure, *especially* when talking about env variables, linker errors, etc. Would've been good to quote the linker errors too.

Comment: @user1811265 This way ... what? Looks like a link didn't get included.

Comment: Oh, hate when internet provider deals with problems for "an hour or two".. Sory. That was: get hstore function handler with load_external_function, cast it to a proper function pointer type and use that pointer just as usual fuction mame. That worked with extern functions. So thank you very-very much!!

Comment: @user1811265 You'll want to check carefully to make sure the proper memory context setup is done when calling it that way, rather than via the fmgr. Certainly an interesting way to do it.

Comment: @user1811265 Updated again with reference to another option, `load_external_function` from `fmgr.h`.

Comment: Now i do `load_external_function` for every function i need only once in `_PG_init()` to avoid function lookup overhead. These calls are made in a subtransaction to prevent module loading failure in case hstore extension is not installed or its API changes in time. The pointers are stored in `TopMemoryContext` and `pfree`d in `_PG_fini()`. I don't see postgresql switches memory context when i call hstore cause its returned-by-ref values seem to be ok, so there's no need to switch to the top context for every hstore call manually. Is that safe enough way?

Comment: @user1811265 I'm not sure, honestly. If it works and you can't find evidence of leaks it's probably OK. I'd need to do more research than I can currently spend the time on to be sure.

Comment: Could you just give some advice on how to do such research? As you can see i'm not very good at pg backend understanding..

Comment: @user1811265 The #1 resource is the source code; that's what I'd be reading.