# How can I use internal PostGIS functions in my own PostgreSQL extension?

Tags: c, postgresql, postgis

Is there a stable and portable way to make use of PostGIS-functions in my own PostgreSQL extension?
I would like to process the geometry type with functions like intersects in my c code by directly calling this functions from the postgis-$version.so (in PostgreSQL's $libdir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally do this by invoking the SQL-level PostGIS functions via either the `SPI` or via `fmgr` fast-path calls.

See [this related question about using hstore from C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13302682/398670).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The _load_external_function_ option will work for me in most cases. The main disadvantage is that I can not use the original struct, but rather the pg-Datum must be sufficient. It seems that this is the best way right now.

Comment: @ptrb Yeah... I'd like to see Pg have a better extension-to-extension C API. In theory right now you can just define a header with the data types used by the other extension, but in practice they tend to use helper functions for Datum conversion etc that you'd want to use. You can probably even load the postgis headers in your ext - you won't get errors about undefined functions unless you try to actually call any of the extern functions directly. You can't link directly to symbols in the other extension but you may be able to `load_external_function` such functions and use them.